# Ruby on Rails: How to show all data in a Ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, scope

Within Ruby on Rails, what's the best way to find out what data a variable has? For example, let's say I have `@customer`, and I know that `@customer` will allow me to print `@customer.name`, `@customer.address`, and `@customer.phone`, but I don't know what other data `@customer` allows in the specific view I'm working in. How can I find out what data `@customer` contains within my current view?

**How can I find out what data I can access within a variable in Ruby on Rails from within my current view?**

Comment: What about @customer.methods ? will it work for you?

Comment: Do you mean persisted data, data in the DB? Or just `instance_variables`, or...?

Comment: @customer is an object, and it's going to respond to whatever set of messages it knows how to respond to.  What's the underlying problem that you are trying to solve?  Your controller is setting that variable to something that should be well defined...

Comment: `pp @customer` in your controller will reveal all its fields and values. Alternatively you could get a debugger going in you IDE and inspect `@customer`.

Comment: I'm mostly a front end developer right now, working within a Rails app written by other developers. We have a lot of data being pulled into views from a database, defined I believe by controllers and models. In this case, our actual "variable" (I'm not sure I'm calling it the right thing) contains data from rows in a table in the database. I have `@employee`, and know that there are a lot of columns in the employees table. I don't know how much of that data is being pulled into the view I'm working on. I'km trying to figure which "sub-variables" are available to me in this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to 'debug' and use a view for it, you could use `debug @var` or `puts @var.inspect`.

But the best and cleaner way I have found is using the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry). Just `cd` into the variable and then `ls` to show all the methods and attributes.